# How to do AddComponent(new someClass) in unity？

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to do this in unity

```cs
MyClass myclass = new MyClass ();
myclass.doSomeThing();
GameObject myObj = new GameObject();

myObj.AddComponent(mclass);
```

How should I do it? If I have to do it this way

Comment: That's not how it works, AddComponent needs a Component type and those cannot be created with new, they are created with AddComponent. You are creating a basic c# type class so those are simply connected to the Component via referencing.

Comment: You also dont do new gameobject in unity.

Comment: `var myClass = myObj.AddComponent<MyClass>(); ` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html

Comment: @BugFinder [`new GameObject()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-ctor.html) is actually one of the exceptions ;) This will create a new empty GameObject in the scene so in this case `var myclass = new GameObject("someName").AddComponent<MyClass>();` would be perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

You can only add classes as a component, which derive from MonoBehaviour.
There is no need to create an instance of the class - simply do:

```
GameObject myObj = new GameObject();
myObj.AddComponent(MyClass);
```

This will create a component and add it to your GameObject.